# ./manage.py test of Django 1.4 gives a Thing2Literal import not found on google appengine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql

I followed the steps here https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/django and it ran well with django 1.3.1. Now up to Django 1.4 and gives a funny stack trace. I would paste the relevant part of the message here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.test.utils import get_runner
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/test/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.test.client import Client, RequestFactory
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/test/client.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.test import signals
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/test/signals.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.db import connections
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/dumb906/woody/py/mdlr/django/db/utils.py", line 44, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms' isn't an available database backend.
   Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
       'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
   Error was: cannot import name Thing2Literal
```

Any help? Some one  said it needs to be compiled http://django-irc-logs.com/2012/mar/27/ ?

Comment: Please don't reference external sites like pastebins for your question; data there tends to go away unexpectedly.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Since the problem is with importing Thing2Literal that is used by adapt_datetime_with_timezone_support function from django/db/backends/mysql/base.py and according to this:
https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/17596/django/trunk/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py this is important only to datetime objects that bypass the model layer and are used with raw sql. So i decided it is not important for me and I messed a bit my django/db/backends/mysql/base.py: comment out code that causes trouble (import of Thing2Literal, adapt_datetime_with_timezone_support function and line 83 where the function is called)
Of course I upload my django 1.4 customized that way to appengine together with my project and it works.

I would appreciate feedback from those who understand django internals better, whether what i've done is ok assuming i don't use raw sql at all.

Comment: thanks. can you tell me the lines to edit so I can also review?

Comment: here it is: https://github.com/martar/django/commit/c5307e3291d0c0d43bd72b691d521c873134418f

Answer (score -2):

As you can see in the documentation you've linked, Google App Engine support only Django up to version 1.3 (actually 1.3.1).

Comment: ok. nice suggestion but I don't think that is really a solution because I later found out that the library giving this error has to do with MySqlDb and not django.